# PHP unexpected T_Variable with if( ... or ...)

Tags: php

I tried the following first, which seems the most intuitive thing to do:

```
if ($obj->request_method != 'post' || $uid < 1)
    die();
```

But had the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$uid' (T_VARIABLE)
```

So I tried this, which fixed that error.

```
if (($obj->request_method != 'post') || ($uid < 1))
    die();
```

But when I go to another page, where this if is used, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function  () in
```

It is not related to the rest of the code. I'm wondering why simple ifs are failing, is it a sign that I need more sleep?

Comment: This looks very much like you have an unmatched single-quote somewhere in a preceding line.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. Please show us an example to reproduce your error

Comment: 5¢ on Unicode whitespace.

Comment: Bingo! I had to remove a specific space and change it into a new space. Then it worked. Wow.. haha Thanks for the help! :D